# deploying rails app to ubuntu with node.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ubuntu, passenger

I'm deploying a rails app to ubuntu server and have nodejs installed. i've checked the version with `node -v` and it comes back as v0.10.25.

Upon deploying i get this error:

`Message from application: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)`

I know that the solution for this is to add `gem "therubyracer"` to my Gemfile but my question is why do i have to do this?

Is having nodejs not enough? What is the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Passenger as server ?

There seems to be some issue with Rails and NodeJs using Nginx.
If so, try to add 
    env PATH; 
to the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/77 for more informations.

Comment: where abouts in the nginx.conf file? @vincent-prigent

Comment: This is a conf file, add it anywhere, it should work.